# P element doesn't work as a 'div' element?

Tags: html, css

#### HTML

```
<div class="contents">
    <p class="alignCenter"><!-- do not align to center-->
        <img src="http://i50.tinypic.com/1zey0j8.gif" />
    </p>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.contents p{text-align: justify;}
.alignCenter{text-align: center;}
```

When I change from `<p>` to `<div>` it works as it should, but why not the `<p>` element when centering an image?

See **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/126/)**.

Comment: There's a fight on up/down vote for this question. Personaly, I found it interesting.

Comment: [Cross-referenced from Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175666/how-can-i-avoid-down-votes).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `!important` to your class to force your selector to work. That is,

```
.alignCenter{text-align: center !important;}
```

See **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaWuM/2/)**.

See Stack Overflow question *[What is the difference between <p> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226562)* to view the difference between `p` and `div`.

Answer (score 5):

`<p>` is indeed block level. Your problem is your [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). The `<p>`s around your `<img>` tags are inside the `<div id='content'>`. id-based CSS outranks class-based CSS, all other things being equal.

Comment: @user2253835, please take a look at this [link about CSS Specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: "id-based css outranks class-based css, all other things being equal." I don't see any ids in the question...

Comment: @BoltClock: because the code (and the jsfiddle as well) changed the id-based CSS selector to a class based on (after the original post). The problem is still the same: the `.contents p` selector is more specific than the `.alignCenter` selector.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: If only I bothered to click the fiddle in the first revision. Thanks for the note.