# Why this "<p><div><br></div></p>" is shown strange in DOM?

Tags: html, dom

When you put `<p><div></br></div></p>` into body, you will get the strange DOM structure like:

```
<p></p>
<div></br></div>
<p></p>
```

Why does this happened? It seems that when `<p>` contains a block element this will happen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8398003/707636 read this...

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate. Q:"Why is `<p><div></div></p>` weird?" - A:"Because that's invalid". "Why is that invalid?" looks like another question. By the way, is the browser *required* by the spec to split the `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 8):

According to the spec, `p` [cannot have nested block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2226592/14955), so the HTML parser automatically closes it before the `div` when building the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

`p` cannot hold a `div` as it's a `block` level element, `p` can only hold `inline` elements, so what you are trying is incorrect.

You can use `span` instead and use `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` in your CSS which will give you same effect and also it is completely acceptable as `p` can hold a `span` as it's an `inline` element.