# Better option with css div and paragraph

Tags: css, html, paragraph

I have a typical code review item where I am requested to use paragraph instead of all divs in my UI code. I am beating my head to trace why was this so important. As p tag more faster than div tag? adding styles to paragraph or div will take same amount of time? This review items seems to be very bad but I want to know if this item is 100% valid?

Comment: what is a code review item?

Comment: Usually text goes within a p tag. It's just good html organization to use more then just div tags for everything, and it might help screen readers to place text in the p.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226562/what-is-the-difference-between-p-and-div

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in SEO for `<p>` and `<div>` tags. You should build your site in the way that makes the most sense: `<p>` for paragraphs, `<div>` for structural div elements.