# Why Aren't My <div> Tags Given Line Breaks?

Tags: html, markup

I wrote a poem, and I re-wrote the poem in HTML so I could include it on my blog. However, even though I wrapped each stanza in `<div>` tags, there are no line breaks between them like there are supposed to be.

According to [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp), "By default, browsers always place a line break before and after the `<div>` element. However, this can be changed with CSS."

You'll note I have no CSS in the code, however, so I don't know why it doesn't have line breaks.

---

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43dn9tr9/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want the stanzas to be separated by white space, which is not the same as line breaks.

You can achieve this by using `<p>` instead of `<div>`.
See https://jsfiddle.net/43dn9tr9/6/

This works because browsers give `<p>` a vertical margin by default. You can make `<div>` behave the same way using CSS.

```
<style>
    div.stanza {
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="stanza">
    This is Stanza 1, Line 1,<br>
    This is Stanza 1, Line 2,<br>
    This is Stanza 1, Line 3.<br>
    This is Stanza 1, Line 4.
</div>

[...]
```

Comment: No, I know that line breaks aren't the same as white space. I thought `<div>` by default worked like `<p>`, that's all. Interesting...

Answer (score 1):

As a brief aside, w3schools is legendary for being abject shite. You may want to try something more reputable.

The output of your HTML is entirely correct- the divs are on new lines. The explanation that w3schools has given you is not really very descriptive, since it implies line breaks that don't really exist. In fact, it's best not to think of layout in terms of line breaks, because that's not how the model works at all.

It might be better to say that divs are blocks which are arranged vertically with respect to each other (ignoring CSS of course). In your output, the three divs are arranged vertically. A good demonstration of this is to replace your br tags with placing each line inside its own div, which achieves an identical result. https://jsfiddle.net/43dn9tr9/3/

Comment: I imagine that the OP wanted additional space every four lines, which would be done using `<p>`. You may also be interested by [a meta question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/8069/6605) and the answer by Robert Harvey.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did before the discussion with Robert. Also note the *“One thing to consider when answering a question that is on the way to migration is that this may push asker closer to question ban at the original site”* part, which is one of the reasons I now avoid answering questions that I vote to migrate.

Comment: @Puppy: Suggestion duly noted. Thank you. However, I've learned most of what I know of HTML and CSS through w3schools and it's helped me so far. Tell me: why is it supposedly "legendary for being abject shite"?

Answer (score 1):

Your **div** tags do have line breaks. Line breaks are the same thing as you get with your **br** tags. That's why **br** tags are called that, they are *line **br**eak* tags.

Without line breaks the line would just continue like this:

```
This is Stanza 1, Line 4. This is Stanza 2, Line 1,
```

I think you are looking for **vertical margin** between your stanzas. If you don't want to use CSS, the P tag has vertical margin by default, which approximates the spacing between stanzas of a poem.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226562/what-is-the-difference-between-p-and-div/3370904#3370904) (but ignore the down-voted first, accepted answer).