# ng-show is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJs since long time but finding a strange issue.

**The below code works well**

```js
var app=angular.module("list",[]);
  app.controller("myctrl",function($scope){  
     $scope.get=function(){
        $scope.thiss = false;
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- This code works well-->
<div ng-app="list" ng-controller="myctrl" ng-init="thiss=true">
  <p>
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    {{thiss}}
    <p ng-show="thiss">Show Content</p>
    <p ng-show="!thiss">Hidden Content</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

**Facing issue with below code**

If I am using following code to declare ng-app and ng-controller in HTML as below, It's not working. Strange issue

```
<!-- This code doesn't update scope for ng-show -->

<div ng-app="list">
   <p ng-controller="myctrl" ng-init="thiss=true">
    <button ng-click="get()">Click</button>
    {{thiss}}
    <p ng-show="thiss">Show Content</p>
    <p ng-show="!thiss">Hidden Content</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Is there any important concept I am missing with AngularJS.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @fatman : No, It doesn't show any console errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p>` is a block-level element.
As per [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

The `p` element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

If nested, when HTML parser encounters inner `p` element(`<p ng-show="thiss">Show Content</p>`) it will *implicitly* close outer `<p ng-controller="myctrl"...>` element.

So, once the parsing is done

```
<div ng-app="list">
    <p ng-controller="myctrl" ng-init="thiss=true">
        <button ng-click="get()">Click</button> {{thiss}}
    </p><!-- paragraph is implicitly closed. So, "thiss" value is not available to ng-show -->
        <p ng-show="thiss">Show Content</p>
        <p ng-show="!thiss">Hidden Content</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

You can find more discussion about nesting block elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015804/nesting-p-wont-work-while-nesting-div-will) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291467/nesting-block-level-elements-inside-the-p-tag-right-or-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

the ng-init directive fails to bind to the scope of the declared controller when declared like this.

Answer (score 0):

try to use "ng-init='thiss=true'" with ng-app div.

Answer (score 0):

In second code  you are using

tag as container which is wrong ,  tag can element like button and

itself which is fine but you should not put these element under

tag just remove p tag for and put div it will work fine.

Comment: Provide me working example with jsfiddle.
Is there any official document that says you can not take tag as container or as p?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226562/what-is-the-difference-between-p-and-div

Comment: please go through above link you will get your answrr