# lxml etree HTML parser changes order of nodes (<center> inside <p>)

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I'm currently facing an issue where I can't explain the etree behaviour. Following code demonstrates the issue I am facing. I want to parse an HTML string as illustrated below, change the attribute of an element and reprint the HTML when done.

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

string = "<p><center><code>git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git</code></center></p>"
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
test = etree.fromstring(string, parser)
print(etree.tostring(test, pretty_print=True, method="html")
```

I get this output:

```
<html><body>
<p></p>
<center><code>git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git</code></center>
</body></html>
```

As you can see (let's ignore the `<html>` and `<body>` tags etree adds), the order of the nodes has been changed! The `<p>` tag that used to wrap the `<center>` tag, now loses its content, and that content gets added after the `</p>` tag closes. Eh?

When I omit the `<center>` tag, all of a sudden the parsing is done right:

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

string = "<p><code>git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git</code></p>"
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
test = etree.fromstring(string, parser)
print(etree.tostring(test, pretty_print=True, method="html"))
```

With correct output:

```
<html><body><p><code>git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git</code></p></body></html>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I have to use the HTML parser because I get a lot of parsing errors when not using it. I also can't change the order of the `<p>` and `<center>` tags, as I read them this way.

Comment: Where is `parser` coming from?

Comment: The same happens if you use `<div>` instead of `<center>`. Perhaps this is some subtle hint from lxml that you should not use `<div>` inside `<p>` (`<div align='center'>` is equivalent to `<center>`). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2226592/407651.

Comment: @panatale1, I edited the code to include the definition of `parser`, it got lost when copying the code (was a few lines higher), shouldn't affect the issue at hand though I think

Comment: @mzjn, thank you for clearing that up. So it looks like lxml is trying to do the good thing here, correcting a situation that shouldn't have happened in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

`<center>` is a block level element.

`<p>` cannot legally contain block level elements.

Therefore the parser closes the `<p>` when it encounters `<center>`.

Use valid HTML - or an XML parser, which does not care about HTML rules (but in exchange can't deal with some of the HTML specifics, like most named entities, such as `&nbsp;` or unclosed/self-closing tags).

Centering content has been done with CSS for ages now, there is no reason to use `<center>` anymore (and, in fact, [it's deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)). But it still works, and if you insist on using it, switch the nesting.

```
<center><p><code>git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git</code></p></center>
```

Comment: I thought block level...? At least that would explain the parser's behavior.

Comment: I think the problem is the use of `<center>` (or `<div>`) as a child of `<p>`.

Comment: Ooh, `<center>` is the block level element. Of course! Thanks for the correction. :)