# When is a block of text considered a paragraph (<p>)?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, screen-readers

Definition of the `<p>` tag according to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p):

> The HTML `<p>` element represents a **paragraph** of text. Paragraphs are usually represented in visual media as blocks of text that are separated from adjacent blocks by vertical blank space and/or first-line indentation.

What is a *paragraph* here? Are we talking about blocks of text with sentences only, or is any piece of text considered a paragraph? For example if I have a list of items and want to display the item count at the top (e.g. *12 results*), should I use a `<p>` or a `<div>`? Does it make any difference  to screen readers?

Comment: The SEO portion was off-topic. You can ask about that on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com). The question about screen readers is on-topic

Comment: `<p>` and `<div>` (as far as text goes) generally are just containers. They hold whatever you put in them.

Comment: Are you familiar with the HTML specification? And why do you think there would be a difference with screen readers?

Comment: In articles you should separate the paragraph with `<p>`  tags, but it's very broad and I guess any answer would be about good/bad practice (Which is based on opinions, i.e - off topic). Read this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2226574/754119 perhaps it will help