# WordPress page: Why is <main> tag wrapped by <p> while <div> is not?

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress page, the `<main>` tags are wrapped by `<p>`s, but `<div>`s are not.

WordPress 4.7.12

**Example 1: Using main tag**

```html
<main>
<div>this is main</div>
</main>
```

results

```html
<p><main></p>
<div>this is main</div>
<p></main></p>
```

**Example 2: Using div#main**

```html
<div id="main">
<div>this is main</div>
</div>
```

results

```html
<div id="main">
<div>this is main</div>
</div>
```

**Question**

What is the trigger to wrap with `<p>`?

**Remarks**

My `page.php` is below.

```php
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme
 */

get_header(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
<?php the_content('<p class="serif">' . __('Read the rest of this page &raquo;', 'kubrick') . '</p>'); ?>
<?php add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's defined in `wp-includes/formatting.php#wpautop` as disribed in [this post](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2011/01/how-to-stop-wordpress-wrapping-images-in-p-tags/).

I edited my `formatting.php` using the code in the post and the `<p>` is eliminated.

1. Open `wp-includes/formatting.php`
2. Find `function wpautop` in it.
3. Copy the function.
4. Open `[your theme folder]/functions.php`.
5. Paste 3 and rename `wpautop` to `wpautop_fork`.
6. Find the line defining `$allblocks = '(?:table|thead|tfoot|caption|col|...`.
7. Add `main` (see the code below.)
8. Register `wpautop_folk` instead of `wpautop`.

My `function.php` becomes following code.

```php
function wpautop_forked( $pee, $br = true ) {
    //...
    // Add 'main' at the tail.
    $allblocks = '(?:table|thead|tfoot|caption|col|colgroup|tbody|tr|td|th|div|dl|dd|dt|ul|ol|li|pre|form|map|area|blockquote|address|math|style|p|h[1-6]|hr|fieldset|legend|section|article|aside|hgroup|header|footer|nav|figure|figcaption|details|menu|summary|main)'
    //...
}
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop_forked');
```

This Q&A is also helpful:

[Stop Wordpress Wrapping Images In A “P” Tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/stop-wordpress-wrapping-images-in-a-p-tag?newreg=dd8b230e4f7e406aacf0cd6db31a3697)

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` element is used to design to describe a container of data.

`<p>` element is designed to describe a paragraph of content.

`<main>` element represents the dominant content of the `<body>` of a document. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document, or the central functionality of an application.

**Note:** As we know `<div>` tag represents container and `<p>` tag represents paragraph of content so the  can not lie in

tag.

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226562/what-is-the-difference-between-p-and-div)

Comment: I want to know why _WordPress_ adds `<p>` to `<main>`.

Comment: The main reason is that `<p>` tag can contain `<main>`. Or maybe there is other reason.